# Angularjs calculate based on formula given

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Im new in Angularjs
and I would like to do something like the following in directive

```
<!--get numb1&numb2 from user input-->
<div>
  <input ng-model="numb1" type=number/>
</div>

<div>
  <input ng-model="numb2" type=number/>
</div>

<!--result display on the following input box, not allow to edit-->
<div>
  <input ng-model="result" formula="some formula here, can be anything" readonly/>
</div>
```

numb1 & numb2 can be change anytime, use $watch instead on ngChange. 
Can anyone guide me on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve your requirement with the following code snippet.

The HTML

```
<div ng-app="demo">
  <div ng-controller="DefaultController as vm">
    <inputs formula="vm.formula"></inputs>
  </div>
</div>

<script type="text/template" id="inputsTemplate">
  <div>
    <input type="number" ng-model="vm.a"/>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="number" ng-model="vm.b"/>
    </div>
  <div>
    <input type="number" ng-model="vm.result" readonly/>
  </div>
</script>
```

The AngularJS code

```
angular
  .module('demo', [])
  .controller('DefaultController', DefaultController)
  .controller('InputsController', InputsController)
  .directive('inputs', inputs);

  function DefaultController() {
    var vm = this;
    vm.formula = 'a + b';
  }

  function inputs() {
    var directive = {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        formula: '='
      },
      template: function () {
        return angular.element(document.querySelector('#inputsTemplate')).html();
      },
      controller: InputsController,
      controllerAs: 'vm',
      bindToController: true
    };

    return directive;
  }

  InputsController.$inject = ['$scope', '$parse'];

  function InputsController($scope, $parse) {
    var vm = this;
    var expressionFunc = $parse(vm.formula);

    $scope.$watchGroup(['vm.a', 'vm.b'], function (newValue, oldValue, scope) {
      if (angular.isDefined(vm.a) && angular.isDefined(vm.b)) {         
        var result = expressionFunc(vm);
        vm.result = result;
      }
    });
  }
```

The jsfiddle link [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ecx092n8/)

The coding style is followed from [angular-styleguide by John Papa](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide) and from [Pro AngularJS by Adam Freeman](http://www.apress.com/9781430264484)

Explanation:

There is a main controller which is having a formula set on its scope such as `a + b` and which is passed to a directive called `inputs` through an attribute called `formula`, this an element directive meaning that it is restricted to be applied only as an individual html element.

The `inputs` directive gets its template from a `script` tag having html content
by using the `template` property of the directive definition. The `inputs` directive has its own controller bound using the controller aliasing syntax.

The `inputs` directive has three objects on its controller scope they're a, b and result and the magic happens in the `InputsController` using the `$parse` service which returns a function when an expression is parsed which can indeed be evaluated on an object to execute that expression and get the result i.e.

```
var expressionFunc = $parse(vm.formula);
var result = expressionFunc(vm);
vm.result = result;
```

Also as we need to watch both a and b objects on the scope, we can use the `$watchGroup` function on the `$scope` object to handle the change events and update the view accordingly.

**Note**: we are only parsing once `var expressionFunc = $parse(vm.formula);` and executing the expression many times `var result = expressionFunc(vm);` this is an important factor and should be considered for quality of the code and for performance.

Answer (score 0):

You are in the same scope, so, you can use `ng-value` in order to set a new value given `numb1` and `numb2`. For example, you formula is `numb1 + numb2`, just try something like this:

```
<input ng-model="result" ng-value="{{numb1 + numb2}}" readonly/>
```

Comment: do in directive and bind back to html

Comment: @Boby.Z  I dont understand u

Comment: I think he need a directive which will evaluate the some formula then that result should bind back to HTML. @Boby am I right?